# LEFT/ RIGHT JOIN Question

Tags: mysql, join

Not sure how to go about this.

I have two tables results and respondents

I need to find out if there are any rows in the respondents table that have completion = 'Complete' but their respondent_id (which is in both the results and respondents tables) is NOT in the results table?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT respondent.* FROM respondent LEFT JOIN results 
ON respondent.id = results.id
WHERE results.id IS NULL;
AND respondents.completion = 'Complete'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simmilar to this perhaps.

```
SELECT r1.* FROM respondents r1
    LEFT JOIN results r2 ON r1.respondent_id = r2.respondent_id
    WHERE r1.completition = 'Complete' AND r2.respondent_id IS NULL;
```